# Can't get compression middleware to work

Tags: express, compression

I am trying to use [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) with `express`. I have a very simple server setup, but it just does not work, my responses will just not be compressed.

This is my server. *For better readability*, I commented out anything that is not about compression, but in reality, everything in this file is being used: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/02fc8d81a8684506d93873c49d699cc6)

Comment: `app.use(compression());`

Comment: See line 13 & 20: https://gist.github.com/LukasBombach/02fc8d81a8684506d93873c49d699cc6#file-srever-js-L20